# error CS1729: 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Files.FileSyncProvider' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using a sample code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763483) for File Synchronisation. But I'm getting the error

> error CS1729: 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Files.FileSyncProvider' does
>   not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments for the following
>   lines in the Method given below:

```
        sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
        destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider( destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

public static void SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay( string sourceReplicaRootPath, string destinationReplicaRootPath, FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
{
    FileSyncProvider sourceProvider = null;
    FileSyncProvider destinationProvider = null;



    try
    {
        sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
        destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider( destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

        destinationProvider.AppliedChange += 
            new EventHandler<AppliedChangeEventArgs>(OnAppliedChange);
        destinationProvider.SkippedChange += 
            new EventHandler<SkippedChangeEventArgs>(OnSkippedChange);

        SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
        agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
        agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
        agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; // Sync source to destination

        Console.WriteLine("Synchronizing changes to replica: " + 
            destinationProvider.RootDirectoryPath);
        agent.Synchronize();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release resources
        if (sourceProvider != null) sourceProvider.Dispose(); 
        if (destinationProvider != null) destinationProvider.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** If I check the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936808.aspx) for `FileSyncProvider` then I can see a constructor which accepts 3 arguments but if I **Go To Definition** of  `FileSyncProvider` in VS2010, I don't see any constructor of `FileSyncProvider` which accepts 3 arguments (of course that's why I am getting an Error).

Comment: Have you checked the versions of the libraries and used a decompiler to view your version?

Comment: I am using Version 1.0.0.0 for both `Microsoft.Synchronisation.Files` and `Microsoft.Synchronisation`

Comment: Right - now decompile them

Comment: If you're using that version then its right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.files.filesyncprovider.filesyncprovider(v=sql.100).aspx  there is no 3 parameter option

Comment: @BugFinder: I saw that the `FileSyncProvider` with 3 arguments is available in Version-SQL Server 2008 R2 . How can i get that?

Comment: download and install SQL 2008 R2..

Comment: @BugFinder: I have downloaded and install (PC Restart) the SQL 2008 R2 but still I don't that version in my "Add Reference"

Comment: no you have to go look for the file in the sql folder..

Comment: does the SQL 2008 R2 need to be installed on the other system too if I want to run my .exe on another system?